# CSS transform invalid property

Tags: css

Why does chrome say this is an invalid value for transform?

I did some calculations in jQuery and this values show up:

```
transform:  matrix(2.5194805194805197, 0, 0, 2.5194805194805197,111.8894168814433px, 442.2284902597403px);
```

what's wrong with this value for transform?

[image: html]

[image: css]

Comment: remove the px from value and it will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bet is that it is invalid because you used `px` units as the last two values. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix):

> Note: Until Firefox 16, Gecko accepted a  value for tx and ty.

So this used to be acceptable in old Firefox, but it is not anymore. As soon as I converted the last two arguments to numbers, Chrome accepted the value. Might want to take a look at [CSS Transforms Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#valdef-transform-matrix).

Comment: lol, but should you use px as last 2 values? I looked at this http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/01/07/css3-matrix-transform-for-the-mathematically-challenged/

Comment: oh I see so for -moz-transform last 2 values have px at the end the others don't

Comment: Sorry, my answer was a little vague, I updated it. That blog post is seven years old, so there is a very good chance that it is outdated.

Comment: @pentzzsolt No, it is not outdated. Firefox 16 has not changed since then!